# ubuntu package for javax.mail

Tags: ubuntu, email, java

I'm in Ubuntu (12.10), trying to send email from Java. So, using javax.mail. Is there an Ubuntu package for this? Seems like a common need. I can download it from Oracle, but I want a package. Googling turns up a package called geronimo-javamail-1.4-spec-java, and a little more googling tells me that Geronimo is an application server, and I don't think that's something I want to get involved with, just to send an email.

Comment: care to explain the drive-by downvote? i think i'm asking a perfectly reasonable question, and in an appropriate forum.

Comment: This is not a help forum, it's a question and answers site. The difference is subtle.

Comment: I asked about installing something with an API instead of a UI. I regret nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no javax.mail package because libraries aren't distributed that way. Of course. That's a job for a build manager, like Maven.

Distributing Java libraries as Ubuntu packages would needlessly tie those projects to Ubuntu. But for system-dependent libraries, it's not uncommon to distribute them that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), [Sendmail](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/) or even [Qmail](http://cr.yp.to/qmail.html).

There is a [list of SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers) servers available on Wikipedia.

Postfix is the default SMTP server on Ubuntu and has [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) available for Ubuntu.

Postfix is a package that is available on Ubuntu, but if you want a Java library available as a package, I don't think that exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package in Ubuntu that provides javax.mail as it doesn't ship Java EE (or a standalone javamail). You'll need to downoad it yourself from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html). Besides that, programming questions are rather off-topic here, best go to Stack Overflow for programming help.